# Partial change of dictionary with clojurescript

Tags: clojurescript

I try to write this d3.js's code https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd with clojurescript because I want to use re-frame framework.

But I could not find any solution because it has the process of changing values in a dictionary such as the function #'collapse.

I have a problem. 
Can ClojureScript write changing values in a dictionary?

ex.

```
function remove_children (d) {
   if (d.children) {
     d.children = null;
   }
}

family_tree = {
  name: "John",
  children: [
     { name: "Jack",
       children: [
          { name: "Michel"}]},
     { name: "Emily",
       children: [
          { name: "Mike"}]}]
};

jack = family_tree.children[0]
remove_children(jack)
```

```clj
;; in clojurescript ... I have no solution ...
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you're trying to emulate `remove_children`, you would have the function return a new map with the child removed. `dissoc d :children`. If you need mutability, wrap the map in an `atom`.

Comment: The best huge problem is the function "collapse" will be used at any point in that d3.js's code as a click event which associated with any child. It cannot go back to the source parent, so I think immutable data is no longer usable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above, you might run into issues later if you are trying to work with mutable data (for D3) and immutable data (for re-frame).

When possible, use ClojureScript's own data structures and only pass JavaScript objects when iteracting with libraries, eg. you can use `(clj->js my-map)` to [convert a CLJS map into a JS object](http://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.core/clj-GTjs).

If you want to use JS interop to mutate JavaScript objects, that's also possible:

```clj
(def family-tree
  (clj->js
    {
      "name" "John",
      "children" [
         { "name" "Jack",
           "children" [
              { "name" "Michel"}]},
         { "name" "Emily",
           "children" [
              { "name" "Mike"}]}]
    }))

;; Check if family-tree looks like expected:

cljs.user=> family-tree
#js {:name "John",
     :children #js [#js {:name "Jack",
                         :children #js [#js {:name "Michel"}]}
                    #js {:name "Emily",
                         :children #js [#js {:name "Mike"}]}]}

;; Define remove-children and Jack using interop:

(defn remove-children [elem]
  (set! (.-children elem) nil))

(def jack
  (-> family-tree .-children (get 0)))

;; Test them

cljs.user=> (remove-children jack)
nil

cljs.user=> family-tree
#js {:name "John",
     :children #js [#js {:name "Jack", :children nil} ;; <== Children were deleted
                    #js {:name "Emily",
                         :children #js [#js {:name "Mike"}]}]}
```